# logical and (&&) while searching for patterns in text file in bash

Tags: bash

in the code below I am attempting to prompt the user to search for, 1) a number, 2) an even or odd number, 3) a big or small number. If the user's number exists and they have entered "odd" and "small" for the above prompts then I wish to simply output all of the numbers within the document.txt. P.s. I know this does not make much sense as you would expect a specific search of odd and small numbers, rather than just echoing all numbers from the file, but this is what I'm doing.

```
#!/bin/bash

file1=document.txt
read -p 'Enter the number to be searched for: ' num
read -p 'Type "even" for an even number match or "odd" for an odd number match: ' num_type
read -p 'Type "big" for a big number or "small" for a small number: ' num_size
if grep "$num" $file1 && [[ "${num_type}" == "odd" ]] && [[ "${num_size}" == "small" ]]; then
    echo $(grep "$num" "$file1") result
else
    echo "lol"
fi
```

The issue I have is that if the above prompts are entered correctly (e.g. the num exists, and the user enters odd and small) then the script runs fine. However, when the user does not enter odd and small, the script runs the same way except the word "lol" is simply added to the bottom of the list of numbers, where I am aiming to simply have the word "lol" as the only output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's really not clear what this code is supposed to do. You seem to have misspelled one variable (`file1` vs `file`) and you have no definition for `pattern`. Could you please provide a [mre] with a simple sample input file (one or two lines) and expected output for different input cases?

Comment: The output from `if grep` will be sent to standard output; probably use `grep -q` if that's what you are trying to avoid. This is a trivial and common duplicate if that's your actual question.

Comment: @tripleee sorry about that, I made the changes to the script. I am new to bash so I am not sure exactly how to word my question. However, I aim to output all numbers that match the input from the user, that is assuming they enter a num that exists, enter an "odd" num_type and enter a "small" num_size. If the user does not enter an "odd" num_type or "small" num_size, then I just want the script to output "lol". The issue I was having was when the incorrect prompts were entered the script would output all of the numbers anyway and just add lol to the bottom of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just run the `grep` once and then decide what to do with the output.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

file1=document.txt
read -r -p 'Enter the number to be searched for: ' num
read -r -p 'Type "even" for an even number match or "odd" for an odd number match: ' num_type
read -r -p 'Type "big" for a big number or "small" for a small number: ' num_size
if [[ "${num_type}" == "odd" ]] && [[ "${num_size}" == "small" ]] && result=$(grep "$num" "$file1"); then
    echo "$result result"
else
    echo "lol"
fi
```

I reordered the `if` conditions so we don't run `grep` at all if we don't need to.

Notice also the use of `read -r`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> grep "$num" $file1
> ```

as `grep` does, it outputs matched lines. Silence it with `-q`.

```
if grep -q "$num" $file1
```